# Best approach to avoid using the sa login to acces my DB from my application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I developed an ASP.NET MVC application which queries an SQL Server database. Until now, I used the sa login to query my DB but I know this is not a good idea.

**My question**: I don't know how to proceed to use another account to access my DB from my application.

- Do I have to create a new login in `\Security\Logins\`

or

- Do I have to create a new user in `\Databases\PLATONDB\Security\Users\`

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need both.
A user or group for \Security\Logins\ and an assignment in  \Databases\PLATONDB\Security\Users\,
which can be done in one step by setting the default database for the Login to PLATONDB

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it in the /security/users folder of the database and assign the right permissions.

Loads of information and tutorials around this subject can be found on the internet though..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/fcbe9a07-6d93-4f9e-95e7-84b99a721d23